# Can you use a table to fill a jQuery Autocomplete textbox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, autocomplete

Can't find anything on the Googles on this, so I figured I'd ask.  I'm taking the basic jQuery Autocomplete example:

```
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
 });
 </script>
```

However, in my real-world application I need to read the values from the field [PayerName] in the table [tblPayer] rather than use a hard-coded list.

How would I go about doing this?

Just to be clear, the data will be coming from a SQL Server database on our Intranet.

**Edit:**

[This example here](http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/dynamic-autocompletion-using-jquery/) appears to be very similar to what I want, but it looks like it uses php and MySQL, and I don't really understand those languages and exactly what's going on.  If anyone could translate that stuff to an ASP/SQL Server environment, it'll probably work for me.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758217/how-to-use-ajax-autocomplete-extender-to-fill-data-from-database-using-webservic

Comment: I should add this to the question, but this is from a SQL Server on our Intranet.  Not sure if that's considered a "webservice" or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this answers your question.

```
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

var data = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: function(req, add) {
  add($.map(data, function(el) {
    return {
      label: el
    };
  }));
 },
 select: function(event, ui) {
  alert(ui);
 }
 });
});
```

Comment: This appears to still use the hard-coded array.  I need to use data from a SQL table.

Comment: How are you going to query the SQL and in what format the data will come as? I you can be more clear I can try to help you on this. Are you planning to use Ajax call to the server to get data?